# With the Ursina game engine, how would I scale a Button to Text when fit_to_text() provides unexpected results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, game-engine, ursina

I am currently writing a class as a derivative to the Button class, creating "Text Buttons" in their stead.  However, while I was testing the Button class itself, I seem to be missing something about the Button's surface scaling, rather than scaling both the Text and the Button.

How do I actually make the Button fit to its text?

Relevant codeblock:

```py
        self.button = Button(text = self.textinput,
                             color = color.rgba(0,255,0,255),
                             text_color = color.rgb(self.unhovered[0],
                                                    self.unhovered[1],
                                                    self.unhovered[2]),
                             x = self.position[0],
                             y = self.position[1],
                             on_click = self.click)
        self.button.fit_to_text()
```

Result:
[image: As you can see, the physical button is much larger than the text.]

All related code:

```py
window.fullscreen = True
window.color = rgb(0,0,0)

Text.size = 0.06
Text.default_font = 'font/silver.ttf'
Text.default_resolution = WINDOW_HEIGHT * 2 * Text.size

class TextButton():
    def __init__(self, textinput = str, position = tuple, hovered = tuple, unhovered = tuple, *click):
        self.position = position
        self.textinput = textinput
        self.hovered = hovered
        self.unhovered = unhovered
        self.click = click
        self.button = Button(text = self.textinput,
                             color = color.rgba(0,255,0,255),
                             text_color = color.rgb(self.unhovered[0],
                                                    self.unhovered[1],
                                                    self.unhovered[2]),
                             x = self.position[0],
                             y = self.position[1],
                             on_click = self.click)
        
        self.button.fit_to_text()
        self.button.on_mouse_enter = Func(setattr,
                                        self.button,
                                        'text_color',
                                        color.rgb(self.hovered[0],
                                                  self.hovered[1],
                                                  self.hovered[2]))
        self.button.on_mouse_exit = Func(setattr,
                                        self.button,
                                        'text_color',
                                        color.rgb(self.unhovered[0],
                                                  self.unhovered[1],
                                                  self.unhovered[2]))
        
        self.button.on_click = self.click
        
        
button = TextButton('testbutton',
                    position = (0, 0),
                    hovered = (255, 0, 0),
                    unhovered = (255, 255, 255))
```

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think `Text.size = 0.06` is the culprit here. There's some padding around the text built in when using fit_to_text() and that becomes too large when changing the default text size.

Since you made the text size more than twice as big, the padding will also be more than twice as large, because it takes the Text.size into consideration. I also think you font is kind of small or something, since it looks smaller than the default one. Doing `self.button.text_entity.scale *= 2` might do the trick for just making the text larger.

If you just want to increase the size of the button, you could do `self.button.scale *= 2` on the next line.

Here's the source code for Button.fit_to_text():

```py
def fit_to_text(self, radius=.1):
        if not self.text_entity.text or self.text_entity.text == '':
            return

        self.text_entity.world_parent = scene
        self.scale = (
            (self.text_entity.width * Text.size * 2) + self.text_entity.height * Text.size * 2,
            self.text_entity.height * Text.size * 2 * 2
            )
        self.model = Quad(aspect=self.scale_x/self.scale_y, radius=radius)
        self.text_entity.world_parent = self
```

As you can see, it's not very complicated and some of the complexity comes from keeping the round corners and adding padding around the text. If all you want is to add a background to some text, that would be easy to implement like this:

```py
b = Text('some text')
bg = Entity(model='quad', parent=b, origin=b.origin, scale=(b.width, b.height), color=color.black, z=.1)
```

Comment: Ahh, pokepetter themself!  Yes, I'm beginning to fool around with the `text_entity.scale` for the ideal result.  I'm  rendering the green quad for debugging purposes, but in a perfect world i'd want the user to just be able to hover over the text, as though the text were the collider and the quad lay invisible.  This is why i'm trying to minimize padding.  Since `button.scale` scales both the button and the text, text_entity may be my best bet.

Comment: I added a padding parameter to fit_to_text now, so it's more customizable. So `button.fit_to_text(radius=0, padding=Vec2(0,0)` should get you the result you want.

Answer (score -1):

The Button class in Ursina has a method called scale_to_text() which can be used to scale a button to fit its text.

If the results of fit_to_text() are unexpected, you can try using scale_to_text() instead.

Comment: I have looked in ursina/prefabs/button.py and see no such method, if you have this method would you source its location for me?